# Relative URL inside $ajax with asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, razor, relative-path

I know one can use this function

```
@Url.Action("MyInfo", "Home")
```

to avoid the hardcoding of urls, but my `$.ajax` calls are in a separate .js file. Would the above still work?

From my knowledge, the `@Url.Action` will only work inside the Razor file. But considering that we are advised to use non-obtrusive JS, I am not quite sure how I would use the `@Url.Action`.

Please advise.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Would the above still work?

No.

> From my knowledge, the @Url.Action will only work inside the Razor file

Your knowledge is correct.

> But considering that we are advised to use non-obtrusive JS, I am not
>   quite sure how I would use the @Url.Action.

You could use HTML5 data-* attributes on some DOM element that you are unobtrusively enhancing (unless this element is already a `<form>` or an anchor in which case it already contains an url):

```
<div id="foo" data-url="@Url.Action("foo")">Hello</div>
```

and then in your separate javascript file:

```
$(function() {
    $('#foo').click(function() {
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        // TODO: do something with the url
    });
});
```

Comment: If you have a `form` already just do this: `var url = $('form').url;`.

Answer (score 4):

Add a function parameter for the relative paths. E.g., in your View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var path =  "@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")";

   someAjaxMethod(path)
</script>
```

and in your external js file:

```
function someAjaxMethod(path)
{
   var data = {};
   $.ajax(path, data)
}
```

Comment: This example doesn't show a good approach, because path variable is now global. It would be better to use some namespacing for global URLs or "data-url" approach for local urls

Comment: I agree it's not the best answer, and I prefer @Darin's approach, but it's still valid for simple scenarios.

Comment: Sorry, but you rollbacked my edit with real improvements to the code that even doesn't work (syntax error)? I would downvote twice if I could. You can write any code you won't but no one should ever copy it!

Comment: Wow. If you think it's so bad, then write your own answer. I'm not sure why it even matters since there's another accepted answer.